# ExtractValue SQL returning multiple values from XML nodes

Tags: mysql, xml, extract-value

I have the below XML

```xml
<Attributes>
    <Map>
       <entry key="ABC">
          <value>
           <List>
              <String>12 3</String>          
              <String>4 56</String>    
           </List>
         </value>
       </entry>
    </Map>
</Attributes>
```

The below SQL

```
SELECT COALESCE(
                 ExtractValue(
                               attributes, 
                               '/Attributes/Map/entry[1]/value/List/String'), 
                'N/A'
                )

  FROM mytable
```

is returning the below

```
12 3 4 56
```

How can I get results in separate rows

12 3

4 56

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS version .

Comment: Presumingly your DBMS is MySQL, isn't it? Please tag the DBMS you're currently using.

Comment: Yes, I am using MYSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using MySQL.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e3f0b869a82a201c8ab13f5b847e05f9)

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
CREATE TABLE tbl (ID INT, attributes TEXT);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
(1, '<Attributes>
    <Map>
        <entry key="ABC">
            <value>
                <List>
                    <String>123</String>
                    <String>456</String>
                </List>
            </value>
        </entry>
    </Map>
</Attributes>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID, REPLACE(COALESCE(ExtractValue(attributes,
     '/Attributes/Map/entry[1]/value/List/String'), 'N/A'), ' ', ', ') as tokens
FROM tbl;
```

**Output**

| ID | tokens |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123, 456 |

Comment: I can not use Replace as my node values also has spaces and I do not want spaces on to be replaced with commas on them.

Comment: You are playing games here. You need to provide ##1-4. Please see my original comment to the question

Comment: I did not get what you meant by games here ... I am using MYSQL and also gave the XML and the output I'm expecting.

Comment: You need to copy ##1-4 to your question, and use them as sections headers.

Comment: This is the first time i'm posting question in stackoverflow.com.   I believe all the info that are looking is provided, samPle data in the above XML,  output that I'm expecting, SQL database is MYSQL.